# How can I make a curve border using CSS3?

Tags: css

I have added 2 pictures here. You can see that first curve is down curve and second one is up curve.

Now, I have a rectangle box using CSS. I want to make the top and bottom border should be like the picture.

I can use CSS `border-radius` property to make a border curve. But I don't understand how can I make this type of border curve using CSS3?

[image]
[image]

**Updated:**

Here is the full output I desire:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `before` `after` to achieve this

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
div:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -10%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Update** 
after OP's recent comment, here you can add content in `content-main` div

```css
.content{
  background-color: #333;
  width: 400px;
}
.content-top, .content-bottom{
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #333;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-top:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
.content-bottom:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -10%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
}
.content-main{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  
  <div class="content-top"></div>
  <div class="content-main">

    <h1>Cat</h1>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS11TbGOYA0EmL-usNpArFE8o17OSRSilYYohX1lgyxaP43M2Pt">


  </div>
  <div class="content-bottom"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. can I decrease or increase the curve?

Comment: Yes just change border radius of before and after elements as per your need

Comment: can you check my updated question? I have uploaded the original image with top and bottom curve.

Comment: see my updated question and good luck with your project

Comment: Awesome brother :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using two Divs one with black background and the children with white background and rounded borders. The wrapper should have a padding to simulate border thickness:

```css
#wrapper{
background:#000000;
width:600px;
height:200px;
padding:10px;
}
#roundCurve{
background:#ffffff;
width:600px;
height:200px;
border-bottom-left-radius:50% 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius:50% 50px;
border-top-left-radius:50% 50px;
border-top-right-radius:50% 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="roundCurve"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its should be reverse curve. like top one is showing upper curve but its should be down curve like the picture I have uploaded.

Comment: The top border should look like a boat curve.

Comment: For Edited image, you can attach the top half of my answer to the bottom of content and vice versa @creativeartbd

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can follow:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.roundCorner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 2em;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
.roundCorner:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  top: 0;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 3em 3em;
  content:'';
  background: black;
}
.roundCorner:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 1.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 3em 3em 0 0;
  content: '';
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="roundCorner"></div>
```

You can change background of `body`, `.roundCorner`, `.roundCorner:before`, `.roundCorner:after` to see how it's working.

Comment: can you check my updated picture which showing the actual curve style?